# Error variable session! 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

Tags: c#, asp.net

Mi problemas es el siguiente quiero usar variables de session y pasar datos de una 
pagina a otra

dejo mi el codigo de mi boton

```
 protected void btnAnalisis_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Session["FechaDesdeAnalizar"] == null && Session["FechaHastaAnalizar"] == null)
        {

            txtfechaDesde.Text = Session["FechaDesdeAnalizar"].ToString();

            txtFechaHasta.Text = Session["FechaHastaAnalizar"].ToString();               

            Response.Redirect("~/PruebasAutomaticas.aspx");
        }


    }
```

pero cuando ingreso valores y hago click en el boton me tira la error diciendo 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

Alguna idea de donde me estoy equivocando

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Tu if está mal. debe ser `!=` en lugar de `==`:`if (Session["FechaDesdeAnalizar"] != null && Session["FechaHastaAnalizar"] != null)`

Comment: Ahora no me tira el error! pero no guarda nada la variable session. Cuando hago el debug en la otra pagina que quiero mandar los datos me aparece en null los valores

Comment: Es posible que lo que estés intentando en este código sea lo contrario? Es decir, que tu if sea correcto, pero lo que querías es hacer `Session["FechaDesdeAnalizar"] = txtfechaDesde.Text` (es decir, almacenar el valor del text a la variable de sesion???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tus if están indicando todo lo contrario a lo que deseas hacer, así como los tienes, indican que hagan algo **si tus sesiones son nulas**:

```
 if (Session["FechaDesdeAnalizar"] == null && Session["FechaHastaAnalizar"] == null)
```

Cuando entra a tu condición, trata se asignar valor con una sesión nula, por eso te marca tu error.

Cuando lo que debería de ser, es que tu if debe hacer algo si tus sesiones **no son nulas**

```
if (Session["FechaDesdeAnalizar"] != null && Session["FechaHastaAnalizar"] != null)
```

Comment: Ahora no me tira el error! pero no guarda nada la variable session. Cuando hago el debug en la otra pagina que quiero mandar los datos me aparece en null los valores

Comment: para que guarde, primero esa sesión debería ya tener un valor, revisa si lo tiene